# Wrapping lines of text inside <pre> with <span>

Tags: jquery

I am looking for a jquery solution to dynamically wrap the contents of my`<pre>` code which is written as below, to wrap each line with a `<span>` and `</span>` element so that my CSS styling for line numbers works.

Any ideas on how to do this?

```
<pre>
This is the first line of pre text.
This is the 2nd line...
This is the 3rd line etc etc you get the ideas...
<pre>
```

The above needs to be amended by jQuery to become:

```
<pre>
<span>This is the first line of pre text.</span>
<span>This is the 2nd line...</span>
<span>This is the 3rd line etc etc you get the ideas...</span>
<pre>
```

Comment: Been looking at the solution here but i get jQuery errors > http://bililite.com/blog/2012/08/05/line-numbering-in-pre-elements/

Comment: Then why don't you include what you've tried (the code and errors) so we can help you?

Comment: No need for that bloated code - Pranav's suggestion below works perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function)** method with callback in jQuery to iterate and update content, where  **[`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)** and **[`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)** methods van use for generate the content.

```js
$('pre').html(function(i, old) {
  return '<span>' + old.split('\n').join('</span>\n<span>') + '</span>';
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre>
This is the first line of pre text.
This is the 2nd line...
This is the 3rd line etc etc you get the ideas...
</pre>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Twitter's bootstrap relay. 
Here is the code that you need to input to the HTML part:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

Paste that into the head of the HTML part, and it will make it a lot easier to use.

Comment: Paste what into the head of the HTML part?